# Photoshop Javascript: search and replace links to external assets

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a PSD with hundreds of linked external assets (for instance `c://myDrive/oldFolder/image1.jpg`).

Is there a way I can use Photoshop Javascript to search and replace these links?  I want to search for all links that contain the path `c://myDrive/oldFolder` and replace that path with `c://myDrive/newFolder`.

I've been searching the Photoshop Javascript documentation but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are all of these assets smart objects? If that is the case instead of replacing the filepath you could Update All Modified content var idplacedLayerUpdateAllModified = stringIDToTypeID( "placedLayerUpdateAllModified" );
executeAction( idplacedLayerUpdateAllModified, undefined, DialogModes.NO );

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this

Comment: If it works I'll write up a real answer. Not for the reputation, for the karma.